# Modifying table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, siblings

I have a small table that I want to modify with some jQuery. I don't have the ability to change the classes on the static HTML so it all needs to be done via jQuery. I'd like to see if the td with class=x says '48 Hour Hold' then the td with class=y in that and only in that tr is changed to Unavilable. I don't know how to exclude things that are in a different tr.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">48 Hour Hold</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">Reference Desk</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".x:contains(48 Hour Hold)")){
    $(".y:contains(Available)").text('Unavailable');
  };
})
```

The result should ultimately look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">48 Hour Hold</td>
    <td class="y">Unavailable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">Reference Desk</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `if` condition, you can just select all the `.x` elements which contain the given string then amend the `text()` of the `next('.y')` element, like this:

```js
$('.x:contains("48 Hour Hold")').next('.y').text('Unavailable');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">48 Hour Hold</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">Reference Desk</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="x">48 Hour Hold</td>
    <td class="y">Available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, quick question. What happens if the <td> I want to change is more than one list element away. I.e.:

<td class="x">48 Hour Hold</td>
<td class="z">More Information</td>
<td class="y">Available</td>

Comment: Then you could use `siblings('.y')` instead

Comment: I think that works. Thank you so much. I appreciate this immensely.